# C++ Reversing a stack using two additional stacks

Tags: c++, stack, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a stack (S) using two other stacks (S1 and S2). This is the code I'm trying:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<int> S, S1, S2;
    S.push(1), S.push(2), S.push(3);

    cout << "The top element of S is: " << S.top() << endl;

    while (!S.empty()) {
        S1.push(S.pop()); 
    }
    while (!S1.empty()) 
        S2.push(S1.pop()); 
    while (!S2.empty()) 
        S.push(S2.pop()); 

    cout << "The top element of S is now: " << S.top() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting (x3) for each time I call pop from inside push.
- stack.cc:14:11: error: reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const int') could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void' `S1.push(S.pop());`

I've tried assigning the popped value to a variable and then calling push with that variable, but it was unsuccessful also.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to read some reference documentation before using any library functions: [`std::stack::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) returns `void`. Another thing is that you don't really need two stacks to reverse a stack. Also, a thing that might go weird is the misuse of the [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). Make sure you are ready to proceed to the coding by taking a C++ refresher from a [verified source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write

```
 S1.push(S.top());
 S.pop();
```

[`std::stack::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) has a `void` return type.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this would be creating a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Brittany No, that's a different issue, and you need to ask a separate question about this. Don't miss to provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` does not return the value popped from the stack. `pop()` returns a `void`. `pop()` removes the value from the stack, and does nothing else.

You need to read the value at the top of the stack, using `top()`, and then call `pop()`.